# "Suggested Edits" Review Audit Giveaway

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Usually when you approve or reject an edit, the review count in the upper-right corner increments immediately.  I've noticed that when the next review item is an **audit**, however, the review count does not increment until after the audit.

For example, my review count was 176.  I then approved the next suggested edit, but the review count did not increment to 177 until I passed the subsequent audit:

[image: Review count incremented only after passing audit.]

Not the biggest deal in the world, but it does make the audit pretty obvious if you have an eye on the review counter.

Comment: Congratulations! This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. **You passed**.

Comment: I'd be wary relying on this; if I recall correctly, the audit counter won't increase if the suggestion had already been approved/rejected. It'll silently pass you along to the next review if your action agrees with the overall action, but it'll give you a message saying "This suggestion was already approved/rejected..." otherwise.

Comment: The behavior you are describing doesn't make sense.  The review counter should **always** increment as your approve or reject the edit because you don't get credit for the audit until ***after*** you review the edit.  The same goes with audits, you get credit after you pass the audit

Comment: @psubsee2003 as I understand the question, you don't get the points for the _previous_ review if this one is an audit.

Comment: but yeah, if you do notice this... you're not a robot.

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry, that's what I was alluding too, definately a bug if it is true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not. I just tried it out. There was a suggested edit, I reviewed it, the counter increased, and I got an audit. Probably the edit was already approved/rejected when you choosed to approve/reject it, because then it doesn't count as an actual review.

Comment: Maybe so...but I'm almost sure I've seen this behavior before several audits.

Comment: @pianoman it is not uncommon for your review not to count because of approval/reject races.  If you are the 4th approval or 4th rejection (which probably happens more than you think), you don't get credit

Comment: @psubsee2003: "3rd rejection"? Don't you mean "4th rejection"?

Comment: @ProgramFOX yes, no idea what I was thinking

Comment: Maybe I do just have a lot of non-counting reviews right before audits.  And I just correlated them like a crazy person :)  Either way, it *is* confusing to have the counter increment sometimes and not other times, but that's a different question...

Comment: @pianoman I just confirmed the same, I eventually got an audit and saw the correct behavior, so it suggests that the behavior you are seeing is not a bug.